# how to write docstring when use flask MethodView

Tags: flask, docstring

i'm confused about:
pycharm show the API param 'unexpected parameter in docstring', so how to write docstring in this case?
Or use google code style 'Attribute'?

Thanks in advance

#### Example

```
from flask import views, request


class BaseApi(views.MethodView):
    
    __params = None

    @property
    def params(self):
        self.__params = {k: v for k, v in request.args.items()}
        
        return self.__params


class UserDetailApi(BaseApi):

    def get(self):
        """Get User Detail
        :param username: string, user name
        """
        self.params.get('name')

        pass
```

[image]